# firefox filechooser filters tiff files

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, filechooser

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/tiff,image/tif,image/x-tif,image/x-tiff,application/tiff,application/x-tiff" />
```

In firefox 39, this input's filechooser incorrectly filters out files with the extension .tif, but will (correctly) no filter .tiff files.  Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: In Firefox 39, under Linux, the file filter is not selected by default but when it's selected, it select `tiff` and `tif`.

Comment: Note that in your screenshot the format is set to `All Supported Types`.

Comment: looks like it is a ffox bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1182948#c10